# Why can't I use this code to overwrite a string?

Tags: c, pointers

**Code**:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
  char *p = "abc";
  printf("p is %s \n", p);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
p is abc
```

---

**Code**:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
  char *p = "abc";
  strcpy(p, "def");
  printf("p is %s \n",p);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could someone explain why this happens?

Comment: As an aside, you have your `#include` directives looking for local files (in the same directory or in a directory specified by `-I` when you compile).  They're system libraries, so you should be able to use `<>` instead of `""`.  I don't know your build setup, but it should make things less complicated to not need to worry about specifically using `-I` on all your system directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because p is pointing to read only memory.

Overwriting data that p points to results in undefined behavior. 
A string literal is any string you specify explicitly in quotes.  All string literals are read only.   (Note: You can use a string literal to initialize a char array.)

You need to instead allocate your own buffer like this:

```
char buffer[4];
strcpy(buffer, "def");
printf("buffer is %s \n", buffer);
```

Answer (score 8):

In your code:

```
char *p="abc";
```

p points to a string literal - you are not allowed to change string literals, which is what your call to strcpy is trying to do. Instead, make p an array:

```
char p[] = "abc";
```

which will copy the literal into something that you are allowed to modify.

Comment: you are not allowed to change string literals - WHY ?

Comment: @aks Because the C Standard says so. The thinking is that the compiler may place them in read-only memory. However, the standard does not require that a compile diagnose problems like yours - it says what you get is "undefined behaviour", in your case a seg fault.

Answer (score 5):

Because `p` points to a **read-only** memory region (__TEXT segment) which contains the string "`abc`".

As you `strcpy` it, a **read-only** memory region is going to be overwritten, which is illegal. So the kernel will SegFault your program.

If you want writable memory, you need to allocate it on the stack

```
char p[1024] = "abc";
```

or on the heap

```
char* p = malloc(1024);
...
free(p);
```

or in the __DATA segment (i.e. a global variable)

```
static char p[1024] = "abc";
```

Comment: Doesn't have to be the TEXT section. Many place it in separate read-only sections (rdata, rodata, etc). Just a sidenote since the main point is, as you pointed out, read-only'iness.

Comment: @joveha: Since I don't know the ELF format I just consider the case in Mach-O :). In Mach-O these stuff are placed in the __TEXT,__const section I think.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is basically just a pointer to read-only data (which is "abc" in your case). You cannot overwrite that with "def".